# Configuring Notifications Emails In TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

How can I set up email notifications for builds fails or succeeded and check-in's on TFS 2017?

When the build fails or even if I check in it does not send the email. How to get the email notification?

Answer (score 1):

To configure notifications, simply follow our official tutorial here-- [Manage your notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-manage-personal-notifications?view=tfs-2017)

[image]

For on-premises TFS, [**you must configure an SMTP server for team members**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-customize-alerts?view=azure-devops) to see the Notifications option from their organization menu and to receive notifications.

Please double confirm your SMTP server which could send the e-mail. Besides, a subscription can be just for you, or if you are a team admin, can be shared by everyone in the team.

If you are setting up a team subscription, try to change to a personal subscription first to check if it works. This will help to narrow down the issue.